# syntax error while using join in sql, same error is shown if i use natural join

Tags: sql, join, natural-join

syntax error while using join in sql, same error is shown if i use natural join

```
select * from
DEPT join EMP;

select * from
DEPT natural join EMP;
```

Comment: First query is invalid, misses ON clause. Second is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `natural join`.  Ever. Be explicit about the `join` conditions.  It does not use properly declared foreign key relationships.  Instead it simply uses columns that have the same name.

Who knows what the join conditions are?  But I would guess something like:

```
select *
from dept join 
     emp
     on dept.department_id = emp.department_id;
```

Comment: Since Gordon takes every opportunity to ride his hobby-horse, I'll ride mine: `natural join` is a sensible and natural operation providing your schema is designed for it. That is, if your columns have meaningful names used consistently, like `department_id`.